# How to adjust all volume levels

Tags: sound, volume-control

Everytime an application is playing audio it gets it own audio level e.g. one chrome window with youtube another with spotify, they get each they own audio level control and always starts at 100%.

I just want ONE universal volume control to adjust ALL volume levels on my system, i do not care for each application. How do i do this?

I am running Ubuntu 19.10, GNOME 3.34.1 On a ThinkPad T490S

[image: Screenshot of volume levels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. You can try to use `alsamixer` :

The general sound volume could be increased / decreased with the *Master* level, which is the 1st on the left. Here are 2 screenshots :

[image]

[image]

You could see that the lonely difference are `MM` / `00` under *Master* (and *Speakers* in my case) volume level; `MM` just said that it's mute, whatever is the volume set. To disable / enable mute, use <kbd>M</kbd>.

Also note that you can send sound via Headphone and Speakers both thanks to `alsamixer` (if you want to do the DJ, it can be useful)

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad to read that :)

Answer (score 0):

Pulse Effects should do the job as well.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseeffects
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the general sound volume level?

Comment: @damadam I think you can't change the systems volume in the application.

Comment: So your answer isn't answering OP question (he wants *ONE universal volume control to adjust ALL volume levels on my system*)

Answer (score 0):

There's supposed to be a small loudspeaker icon on the taskbar (or is it the toolbar?) at the bottom of the screen that when clicked on will provide such an adjustment.  Unfortunately for me, it's disappeared from my screen.